# Can't access external ip of kubernetes deploy on docker desktop in macOS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am running Minikube on Docker in macOS to install Kubernetes locally. I am facing an issue can't access service Kubernetes by external IP. Service type is NodePort.

[image]

Version components I am using

1. kubectl:

```
Client Version: v1.29.0
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.28.3
```

2. minikube

`minikube version: v1.32.0`

3. docker

`Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b`

I run command minikube service web-service, I can access with http://127.0.0.1:52312 but http://192.168.49.2:31856 is no
[image]

How to access http://192.168.49.2:31856 ?
Thanks for any help and reading.